# How can I post data from a raw Php page to a Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project with a raw (. php) page. On this page is a form. I would like to post this form from the raw php page to a controller I have. How, if possible can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried to use a laravel route with post method in your form?

Comment: Yes I did my form action: action="<? route('myroute')?>. However, this doesn't render the form

Comment: What  error are you getting?

Comment: The form just doesn't display. It only displays if I remove the <? route()? > from the action. All I want to do is post this form to a Laravel controller. This page isn't a blade file, just a regular php file

Comment: Try adding your action without the `route`, using the url, like
`/users/store`. As soon as i reach my PC i can test it and give you a better answer

Comment: I also tried the URL method but the form doesn't display either

Comment: Hey man, can you email me I'm being warned about extended discussion in comment. kemoy79@gmail.com. Please and thanks. Also, I did what you suggested and it didn't work. Remeber I'm trying to post to a Laravel Controller function/action.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around online, I found the answer to be that I needed to use API routes. The file is located in Routes/api.php. One can add their routes there so requests from outside the Laravel application can be sent in. Simply add your route there and corresponding action for said route.